# How to convert one2many filed to optgroup in odoo 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, odoo-9

I am try to change the view of one2many relation field to optgroup , so for this, i try in jquery , so for this at first change the widget to selection and after that i try to use jquery for that . here my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    var displayEduacationfield = function(){
      var course_value = jQuery('#oe-field-input-13').val();
      console.log("Hii");
      console.log(course_value);
      var course_value = jQuery('#oe-field-input-13').val();
      if (course_value == "15"){
        jQuery('select[name="x_pg_institution"]').hide();
      }
    };
    displayEduacationfield();
    var restructureCourseSelector = function () {
  jQuery('select[name="x_course_id"]').each(function () {
    var _self = jQuery(this);
    var _parentSelect = _self.parent();
    if(!_parentSelect.is('select'))
      return;
    var selfText = jQuery.trim(_self.text());
    if(selfText == "")
      return;
    _self.data('originalText', selfText);
    var selfText_a = selfText.split('-');
    var groupName = selfText_a.shift();
    var optionName = selfText_a.join('-');
    _self.text(optionName);
    var _group = _parentSelect.find('optgroup[label="'+groupName+'"]');
    if(!_group.length) {
      _group = jQuery(document.createElement("optgroup"));
      console.log("hello");
      _group.attr("label", groupName);
      _parentSelect.append(_group);
    }
    _group.append(_self);
  });
};
restructureCourseSelector();
  })();
</script>
```

but i am not getting any appropriate solution . if You have any idea please share with me .

Answer (score 0):

```
var restructureCourseSelector = function () {
  jQuery('select[name="x_course_id"]').find('option').each(function () 
 {
    var _self = jQuery(this);
    var _parentSelect = _self.parent();
    if(!_parentSelect.is('select'))
      return;
    var selfText = jQuery.trim(_self.text());
    if(selfText == "")
      return;
    _self.data('originalText', selfText);
    var selfText_a = selfText.split('-');
    var groupName = selfText_a.shift();
    var optionName = selfText_a.join('-');
    _self.text(optionName);
     var _group = _parentSelect.find('optgroup[label="'+groupName+'"]');
     if(!_group.length) {
      _group = jQuery(document.createElement("optgroup"));
      _group.attr("label", groupName);
      _parentSelect.append(_group);
     }
    _group.append(_self);
  });
};
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    restructureCourseSelector();
}); 
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    restructureCourseSelector();
});
```

This one work like charm ..